# SQL групировка результатов запроса с суммированием

Tags: sql-server

есть сложный запрос в результате которого видим:

```
Заказчик 1 |  12.3
Заказчик 3 |  0.7
Заказчик 1 |  152.07
Заказчик 1 |  18.69
Заказчик 2 |  0.256
Заказчик 3 |  10.2
```

А нужно чтобы получилось

```
Заказчик 1 |  170.76
Заказчик 2 |  0.256
Заказчик 3 |  10.9
```

какую конструкцию добавить в запрос, субд MSSQL, две сджойненные таблицы.
Спасибо

Comment: Никакую, так как мы не понимаем, как из трех чисел `12.3`, `152.07`, `18.69` Вы получаете `170.76`.

Comment: `select client, sum(v) .. group by client`

Comment: а где же сам запрос?